Given $2\sin x\sin y+3\cos y+6\cos x\sin y=7$, find $\tan^2x+2\tan^2y$ using the vector dot product

Given:
$$2\sin x\sin y+3\cos y+6\cos x\sin y=7$$
Then find the value of $\tan^2x+2\tan^2y$.

I guess that dot product is involved in this but can't figure out how.

This question is similar to: Value of $\sec^2 a+2\sec^2 b$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Interesting question. The linked question was asking about $\sec^2 x + 2\sec ^2 y$, but of course $\tan^2 \theta = \sec^2\theta -1$. The existing answer there was not complete though.

@peterwhy Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a method involving dot product of vectors. Could you help me out with that.
